# How to create HTTP API using Java without any web framework like Spring, Java EE?

Tags: java, rest, http

How to create an HTTP API using Java without any web frameworks like Spring, Java EE?

Comment: How do you think those web frameworks work? Like Spring, Java EE? Did you expect someone to write a web framework for you as an answer?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't know. that's why asked here. If you know how it works under the hood please share it or any links would help me.

Comment: If you want to do this from scratch you'll need to implement a HTTP server yourself.

Comment: @Jesper. Thanks for the info. Spring, Java EE, Jakarta EE are web frameworks. So I don't want to use these. I am trying to implement from scratch so that I can understand how it works under the hood.

Comment: If you want to create an HTTP API, you need Java servlets and servlets are part of the JEE stack.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle so we can't create an HTTP API without web framework like JEE?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle servlets are not the only possible way. You can create your own HTTP server which works with sockets, and implements the HTTP protocol. It would be a lot of work and nobody would do this in practice for any real project, but it is possible...

Comment: @Jesper sure sure but you also don't start to explain how petrol is created when someone asks you how to fill up their car. He's obviously still learning the basics. No need to slap him around the ears with 'implement your own server or http protocol'. All he's asking is a way to create a simple HTTP endpoint with al less frameworks as possible

Comment: Yes, I need to create a simple HTTP API endpoint without any web frameworks.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle As OP has now repeated multiple times; "How do I refine petroleum without using any existing equipment?"

Comment: This Question is far too broad for Stack Overflow? Entire books have been written on networking, sockets, HTTP, and web serving. So I am voting to close as needing focus. If you want to look under the hood, **look at the source code** for a HTTP product. In particular, I’d suggest the source code for the [Simple Web Server](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/408) built into Java 18. Find the source code at the [OpenJDK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

Answer (score 6):

The basics of HTTP are fairly simple. Open a `ServerSocket` to listen for incoming requests. When a connection is made, start a new thread and send the response. That could look like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(8080, 10);
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.append("<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>");
        while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(new HttpReply(s, body));
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then to actually send the response you get an `OutputStream` from the `Socket` and write the required HTTP headers and then the body. Like,

```
class HttpReply implements Runnable {
    private Socket s;
    private StringBuilder body;

    private HttpReply(Socket s, StringBuilder body) {
        this.s = s;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ps.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            ps.println("Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT");
            ps.println("Server: Java");
            ps.println("Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT");
            ps.println("Content-Length: " + body.length());
            ps.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            ps.println("Connection: Closed");
            ps.println();
            ps.println(body);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which will listen on port `8080` of your machine for requests and reply with a basic hello world web page.

[image: Hello World Web Page]

Comment: It should be noted that this HTTP "server" doesn't implement the spec even rudimentary. It does barely enough to trick a browser into displaying the result, but it doesn't even read the request (let alone parse it). A simple HTTP server (at least 1.0) is reasonably simple to write but it's still a lot more code than this.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes. This is the "minimum" for the browser show a page. I also considered making it just `404`.